# Datagridview cell mouseClick event error

Tags: c#, datagridview, mouseevent, picturebox

can you help me to this problem
i have one form production from where i can upload that photo and save it on to the database,
but when i do a `cellmouseclick` event it having some problem [image]

and below is the code for doing so:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANTONIANGGA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FullandStarving;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader dr;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] image = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.txtLink.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    image = br.ReadBytes ((int)fs.Length);

    string dProduksi = DateTime.Parse(dtmProduksi.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

 try{
     con.Open();
     cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Produksi (IDProduksi,IDPhoto,TanggalProduksi,NamaKaryawan,KeteranganPhoto,Photo) Values(@IDProduksi,@IDPhoto,@TanggalProduksi,@NamaKaryawan,@KeteranganPhoto,@Photo)", con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProduksi", txtIdpro.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDPhoto", txtIdPhoto.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TanggalProduksi", dProduksi);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NamaKaryawan", txtNamaKaryawan.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KeteranganPhoto", rxtKtrphoto.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", image);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     MessageBox.Show("Update telah di jalankan");

     con.Close();
     showgridview();
     clear();

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
    }
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        txtIdpro.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtIdPhoto.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        dtmProduksi.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtNamaKaryawan.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        rxtKtrphoto.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtLink.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        // wanna show that picture when you klik cell
        byte[] imgg = (byte[])(dr["Photo"]);
        MemoryStream Strem = new MemoryStream(imgg);
        pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Strem);

    }
```

and if i commend that byte[] that can be like that below :

[image: stack 2]

and if i commend that byte[] that can be like that below :

Comment: Please explation some problem , that you are getting .

Comment: yeah when i click some datacell that image can load automatically, like view you see that callmouseclick event textbox can i handel so if you klik it textbox can print it. so what should i do when picturebox like that when i klik it ?

Comment: can you show all code for me i confuse what you say ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `dr`. You must create in `dataGridView1_CellMouseClick` a select query and than you can do this:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()) { }
```